# Custom keyboard layout stops working randomly

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, microsoft-klc

I created a custom US QWERTZ keyboard layout using Microsoft Layout Keyboard Creator. It's the US layout with the Z and Y keys swapped. I successfully managed to create and install it, the problem arises when I try to use it. When I use it for some time (let's say a few hours) the Z and Y keys randomly swap back to the places they are on the original US layout, despite me still using the US QWERTZ layout. Restarting the computer fixes this problem, but you probably can imagine why I don't want to restart it every single time the keys get swapped.
Does anyone have any idea why this keeps happening and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why the keyboard doesn't work, but perhaps another
solution that builds on the standard US keyboard will be more stable.

You could return to the standard US keyboard, then use the free
[SharpKeys](https://www.randyrants.com/category/sharpkeys/)
to swap the Z and Y keys.

SharpKeys uses a registry hack that will certainly keep working
without fault.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I will try it out.